# Mysql Update and Replace Syntax in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, replace, syntax

I need to eliminate the character (") from a column in my database. I can do in mysql command line by the following command:

```
mysql> UPDATE tName SET colName=REPLACE(colName, '"','');
```

and it works perfectly. Since i need run in php, i have used the following syntax in php but it dosent work :

```
$sql0 = "UPDATE tName SET colName=REPLACE(colName,'"','')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql0)) {
$result0 = "Unwanted Character is removed ";
} else {
$result0 = "Error Filtering is Failed: " . $sql . "<br>" .       mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

any Idea??

Comment: What means `but it dosent work`?

Comment: Obviously a syntax error / typo. Didn't your IDE tell you?

Comment: hi Raptor , thanks for your comment, I use nortpad++ and it did not tell me any thing:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to escape double quotes inside double-quoted strings.

```
$sql0 = "UPDATE tName SET colName=REPLACE(colName,'\"','')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql0)) {
  $result0 = "Unwanted Character is removed ";
} else {
  $result0 = "Error Filtering is Failed: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: Looks like we answered at the same time :)

Comment: and by the second! what a coincidence. here, have a cookie *gives cookie*

Answer (score 3):

Try this one instead :

```
$sql0 = "UPDATE tName SET colName=REPLACE(colName,'\"','')";
```

notice there is a back slash :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use quotes in REPLACE function as:

```
$one = '"';
$sql0 = "UPDATE tName SET colName = REPLACE(colName,'$one','')";
```

**If you echo `$sql0` result is:**

```
UPDATE tName SET colName = REPLACE(colName,'"','')
```